# chrome extension in iframe allow-same-origin blocked

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

manifest.json

```
 {
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Test iframe",
  "version": "1.0",
  "content_scripts": [ {
      "all_frames": true,
      "js": [ "script.js" ],
      "match_about_blank": true,
      "matches": [ "\u003Call_urls>" ],
      "run_at": "document_start"
   } ],
 "permissions": ["\u003Call_urls>"]
}
```

script.js

```
var s = document.createElement("script");
var str='console.log(1);';
    s.type = "text/javascript";
    s.text = str, document.documentElement.insertBefore(s, null);
```

Test: [jsbin.com](http://jsbin.com/kazizohawo/edit?html,console,output)

Error:
**Blocked script execution in 'about:blank' because the document's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-scripts' permission is not set.**

How to get access to sandbox iframe?

*chrome.exe --disable-web-security* -
not working.

Answer (score 1):

You had to add "allow script" in sandbox attribute in the iframe

Comment: This not solution. iframe not need to change